# What function in C can I use to get the date alone separate from time?

Tags: c, date, time

I am building a C program and I need to use time separately and also the date separately. I want to do this without using the structure `struct tm` since I have to send the time and the date to different columns in my database table called `Logs`:

```
int main(){       

       duration = clock() - duration;
       double Duration = ((double)duration)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

       char* IPaddr = inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr);
        int PortNo = ntohs(newAddr.sin_port);
        printf("\n%s %s %d %f\n", task, IPaddr, PortNo, Duration);
        printf("now: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n",tm.tm_mday,tm.tm_mon+1,tm.tm_year+1900,tm.tm_hour,tm.tm_min,tm.tm_sec);

        if (mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO Logs(ClientIP, ClientPort, Job_type, SubmissionTime, SubmissionDate, Duration)
                VALUES(%s, %d, %s, %, %, %f)")) {
                    finish_with_error(con);
                }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to send the time and the date to different columns in my database table called Logs

Comment: *Why* do you not want to use `struct tm`?

Comment: All of the standard time functions in C are documented here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2 Pick the one you like.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question, format it correctly and add all necessary information _there_ and not in a comment.

Comment: the structure does not cater for the two columns in my database

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't use `struct tm`.  You can use the `tm_year`, `tm_mon`, and `tm_mday` fields to construct the data to insert into your date column, and then you can turn around and use the `tm_hour`, `tm_min`, and `tm_sec` fields (from the exact same `struct tm` instance, that is) to construct the data to insert into your time column.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free coding service.  Please post a [mcve] showing what you have done and state the problem your having.  Then we can help you.

Comment: @Steve Summit Does that mean i declare a new variable for date and another for time and store there the respective components of each?

Comment: regarding: `duration = clock() - duration;`  this will not compile nor work correctly as `duration` is not declared and does not contain an initial value.

Comment: @Steve Summit. It has worked as desired, Thanx

Comment: Beware that `clock()` gives an approximate measure of CPU time.  If you want "real time" or "wall clock time", you probably want to use `time()` (or maybe `gettimeofday()` or `clock_gettime()`) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to declare two character arrays, one for the date string and one for the time string, and call `strftime` twice to construct them.
Something like this:

```
char SubmissionDate[20], SubmissionTime[20];
strftime(SubmissionDate, sizeof(SubmissionDate), "%Y-%m-%d", &tm); 
strftime(SubmissionTime, sizeof(SubmissionTime), "%H:%M:%S", &tm);
```